# DRY Rails Metaprogramming - Use Cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, dry

So I've running around my app, applying this particular use case for DRY'ing your app via metaprogramming:

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/16-dry-metaprogramming

In what other ways are you applying metaprogramming to keep your app DRY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a gem called [to_lang](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/to_lang) which makes use of this type of dynamic method definition. It adds a bunch of methods to strings in the form `to_language` which all call a single method with different parameters. [`ToLang::StringMethods`](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/to_lang/blob/master/lib/to_lang/string_methods.rb) in particular is where this magic happens. Doing the same thing without metaprogramming would require the definition of hundreds of methods.